# Problema con comboBox en Python: no sucede nada

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, combobox

¡Hola! Soy yo de nuevo.

Me ha surgido un nuevo problema pero ahora con los comboBox de Python. Lo que pretendo hacer es que al presionar un boton aparezca un comboBox no modificable con varias opciones y una vez elegida la opción correspondiente se realicen otras acciones.

El código va algo así:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
frame1= tk.Frame(root)
frame1.pack()

class OpcionesAElegir():
    def __init__(self):
        self.opcionSi= False
        self.opcionNo= False

    def EleccionOpciones(self):
        if (self.opcionSi): 
            opciones = ["1", "2","3"]
            variableOpciones = tk.StringVar(frame1)
            combOpciones= ttk.Combobox(frame1, state="readonly")
            combOpciones["values"]= opciones
            combOpciones.pack()

            if combOpciones.current(0):
                combOpciones.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>")
                #Linea de código que no lee.
            elif combOpciones.current(1):
                combOpciones.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>")
                #Linea de código que no lee.
            elif combOpciones.current(2):
                combOpciones.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>")
                #Linea de código que no lee.

        elif (self.opcionNo):
            combOpciones.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>")
            #Codigo que si lee.

    def opcion1(self):
        self.opcionSi= True
        self.EleccionOpciones()
    def opcion2(self):
        self.opcionNo= True
        self.EleccionOpciones()

llamadaOpciones= OpcionesAElegir()
botonSi= tk.Button(frame1, text= "Opcion 1", command= llamadaOpciones.opcion1).pack()
botonNo= tk.Button(frame1, text= "Opcion 2", command= llamadaOpciones.opcion2).pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Ahora bien, con esto tengo dos problemas:

1- El comboBox aparece seleccionado por defecto en la ultima opción (opción 3) ¿Cómo puedo hacer que aparezca sin selección?

2.- Al seleccionar una opción diferente no sucede absolutamente nada (en este caso de ejemplo no hay nada mas que hacer pero en mi código principal tengo líneas que no lee) ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que al seleccionar una de las opciones lea el código?

Estoy usando **Python en su versión 3.9.0** y **Tkinter 8.6**

¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Hola! Soy yo de nuevo...

Después de buscar muchísimo y leer como loco multitud de documentación finalmente he dado con una solución a mi problema.

Lo que hice fue crear una funciona a la que llame opcionElegida, dentro de ella una variable que guardaría lo que obtuviera del combobox con el método get() y finalmente unos if que leerían el código que antes no podía según lo que obtuviera de la variable.

En el combobox utilice el método bind y después <> para indicar que se había seleccionado un elemento e inmediatamente después llamar a la función antes mencionada.

El código quedo algo así:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
frame1= tk.Frame(root)
frame1.pack()

class OpcionesAElegir():
    def __init__(self):
        self.opcionSi= False
        self.opcionNo= False

    def EleccionOpciones(self):
        if (self.opcionSi): 
            def opcionElegida(*args):
                combOpcionElegida= combOpciones.get()

                if combOpcionElegida== "1":
                    print("Si Funciona ;D")
                elif combOpcionElegida=="2":
                    print("Tambien funciona")
                elif combOpcionElegida=="3":
                    print("Y este tambien jala")

            combOpciones= ttk.Combobox(frame1)
            combOpciones['values']= ("1", "2", "3")
            combOpciones.state(["readonly"])
            combOpciones.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", opcionElegida)
            combOpciones.pack()

        elif (self.opcionNo):
            print("Este jalaba desde siempre.")

    def opcion1(self):
        self.opcionSi= True
        self.EleccionOpciones()
    def opcion2(self):
        self.opcionNo= True
        self.EleccionOpciones()

llamadaOpciones= OpcionesAElegir()
botonSi= tk.Button(frame1, text= "Opcion 1", command= 
llamadaOpciones.opcion1).pack()
botonNo= tk.Button(frame1, text= "Opcion 2", command= 
llamadaOpciones.opcion2).pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Finalmente y solo si se me es permitido preguntar: ¿hay alguna forma de hacerlo mejor?

Muchas gracias a todos los que vieron la pregunta.

Espero que mi respuesta sea de utilidad a cualquiera que tenga la misma problemática.

¡Hasta la proxima!